# Secure the View in ASP.NET MVC4 : Forms Authentification

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, forms-authentication

I want to render different content in the View for each user. what is the proper way to do that in **Asp.net mbc4**.

I'm looking for something similar to securing views in Spring security :

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">

    This content will only be visible to users who have
    the "supervisor" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.

</sec:authorize>
```

till now I can only secure the access to controllers:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "supervisor")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, you should be able to perform a check on your `User` property:

```
@if(User.IsInRole("supervisor"))
{
//Markup here...
}
```